# How can I make Visual Studio use my database instead of the .mdf file located in App_Data folder in ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, forms, authentication

I am creating an ASP.net Web Application (.NET Framework) in Visual Studio 2019 and I select the ASP.NET MVC template and I use individual user accounts option. On the other hand I have a SQL Server database created by myself (let's call it `DemoDb`).

After Visual Studio creates the template, under `App_Data` folder in the solution explorer, it creates the `.mdf` database file which also includes the `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetUserRoles` etc. tables.

What I want to do is, transfer all the authentication tables to my `DemoDb` database and let Visual Studio use those tables.

I did a lot of research in internet including StackOverFlow. I edited `web.config` files connection string entry to point to my database but it did not work.

Is there anybody WHO will guide me step by step to achieve my goal? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you recreate the identity tables in your own database and change your connection string to use that database, that should provide what you want.  When you say it isn't working, what exactly is the problem?  Can you show your connectionstring (don't put real credentials)

Comment: It is connectionstring `DefaultConnection` in web.config

Comment: I get "Keyword is not supported : "metadata" error. Error happens in Line 155:                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);  in the AccountsController.cs. I have to mention I also use EF Database First.

Answer (score 0):

First Step is Copy (transfer) Identity Tables to your Main Database, then Find "IdentityDbContext" in your project. it should be in "Models\IdentityModel.cs".
then find this code:

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
```

and change "DefaultConnection" to your Connection String.
it's better you do this job, before First Compile.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I copy Identity Tables? Just copy-paste or something else?

Comment: if your project is Code-First, just Do my solution then add migration and update database.
but if your project was compiled before and you have some data on it, it's better using generate script by SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) from that tables with shema and data, then run it on your Main DB.

Comment: I solved the problem myself. I deleted the DefaulConnection entry from `web.config` file. I recreated the Identitiy tables on my own database. Finally i created this entry on web.config file: `<add name="AuthDbContext" connectionString="Server=.;Database=DemoDb;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` and altered `IdentitiyModel.cs` file to point my `AuthDbContext` entry. Thanx to everyone.